# Facebook OAuth Dialog Bug

Tags: facebook

I using OAuth Dialog for asking extra permission.
When I click on "Cancel" button first time on Dilog with permission page I was successful redirect to according my "redirect_uri".
After that if I try ask permission again and click on "Cancel" button againe I was redirect to facebook.com/home page instead of my "redirect_uri".
Is it Facebook bug or my?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. If your user keeps pressing *cancel* Facebook assumes that she's confused and has no interest in the app.

Comment: That page appear only if user click on the button. p.s. for dialog realization I use that approach - developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

Comment: What I said still applies. An app developer could easily trap a non-savvy user inside an app.